Azure DevOps Pipeline fails to download tasks after using latest vmImage: `windows-2019` released on 20240825.1.0
I've noticed my pipelines started failing all of a sudden after being run against the Microsoft-hosted vmImage windows-2019 which we have always been using to build our client's solution, but recently after the 20240825.1.0 release of the image the jobs start failing while downloading and installing the required tasks from the pipeline into the VM. See below a good log from the Initializing job step of our build job when it ran against the previous image build from 20240818.1.0 vs the one from 20240825.1.0 and the failing in installing the same task versions basically:
Starting: Initialize job
Agent name: 'Hosted Agent'
Agent machine name: 'fv-az754-280'
Current agent version: '3.243.1'
Operating System
Microsoft Windows Server 2019
10.0.17763
Datacenter
Runner Image
Image: windows-2019
Version: 20240818.1.0
Included Software: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/win19/20240818.1/images/windows/Windows2019-Readme.md
Image Release: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/releases/tag/win19%2F20240818.1
Runner Image Provisioner
2.0.382.1
Current image version: '20240818.1.0'
Agent running as: 'VssAdministrator'
Prepare build directory.
Set build variables.
Download all required tasks.
Downloading task: PowerShell (2.242.1)
Downloading task: CmdLine (2.244.3)
Downloading task: InstallSSHKey (0.238.1)

Downloading task: Cache (2.198.0)
Downloading task: NuGetToolInstaller (1.238.1)
Downloading task: NuGetCommand (2.244.1)
Downloading task: Bash (3.244.1)
Downloading task: VSBuild (1.231.0)
Downloading task: ArchiveFiles (2.244.1)
Downloading task: PublishPipelineArtifact (1.242.0)
Checking job knob settings.
   Knob: DockerActionRetries = true Source: $(VSTSAGENT_DOCKER_ACTION_RETRIES) 
   Knob: AgentToolsDirectory = C:\hostedtoolcache\windows Source: ${AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY} 
   Knob: UseGitLongPaths = true Source: $(USE_GIT_LONG_PATHS) 
   Knob: AgentPerflog = c:\vsts\perflog Source: ${VSTS_AGENT_PERFLOG} 
   Knob: EnableIssueSourceValidation = true Source: $(ENABLE_ISSUE_SOURCE_VALIDATION) 
   Knob: AgentEnablePipelineArtifactLargeChunkSize = true Source: $(AGENT_ENABLE_PIPELINEARTIFACT_LARGE_CHUNK_SIZE) 
   Knob: ContinueAfterCancelProcessTreeKillAttempt = true Source: $(VSTSAGENT_CONTINUE_AFTER_CANCEL_PROCESSTREEKILL_ATTEMPT) 
   Knob: ProcessHandlerSecureArguments = false Source: $(AZP_75787_ENABLE_NEW_LOGIC) 
   Knob: ProcessHandlerSecureArguments = false Source: $(AZP_75787_ENABLE_NEW_LOGIC_LOG) 
   Knob: ProcessHandlerTelemetry = true Source: $(AZP_75787_ENABLE_COLLECT) 
   Knob: UseNewNodeHandlerTelemetry = True Source: $(DistributedTask.Agent.USENEWNODEHANDLERTELEMETRY) 
   Knob: ProcessHandlerEnableNewLogic = true Source: $(AZP_75787_ENABLE_NEW_PH_LOGIC) 
   Knob: EnableResourceUtilizationWarnings = true Source: $(AZP_ENABLE_RESOURCE_UTILIZATION_WARNINGS) 
   Knob: IgnoreVSTSTaskLib = true Source: $(AZP_AGENT_IGNORE_VSTSTASKLIB) 
   Knob: FailJobWhenAgentDies = true Source: $(FAIL_JOB_WHEN_AGENT_DIES) 
   Knob: CheckForTaskDeprecation = true Source: $(AZP_AGENT_CHECK_FOR_TASK_DEPRECATION) 
   Knob: LogTaskNameInUserAgent = true Source: $(AZP_AGENT_LOG_TASKNAME_IN_USERAGENT) 
   Knob: UseFetchFilterInCheckoutTask = true Source: $(AGENT_USE_FETCH_FILTER_IN_CHECKOUT_TASK) 
   Knob: Rosetta2Warning = true Source: $(ROSETTA2_WARNING) 
Finished checking job knob settings.
Start tracking orphan processes.
Finishing: Initialize job

vs
Starting: Initialize job
Agent name: 'Hosted Agent'
Agent machine name: 'fv-az841-440'
Current agent version: '3.243.1'
Operating System
Microsoft Windows Server 2019
10.0.17763
Datacenter
Runner Image
Image: windows-2019
Version: 20240825.1.0
Included Software: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/win19/20240825.1/images/windows/Windows2019-Readme.md
Image Release: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/releases/tag/win19%2F20240825.1
Runner Image Provisioner
2.0.382.1
Current image version: '20240825.1.0'
Agent running as: 'VssAdministrator'
Prepare build directory.
Set build variables.
Download all required tasks.
Downloading task: PowerShell (2.242.1)
Downloading task: CmdLine (2.244.3)
Downloading task: InstallSSHKey (0.238.1)
##[error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Finishing: Initialize job

Is there a way to specify in the vmImage yml property which version of the VM image one would like to use as a "requirement"? Didn't see anything like that in the spec, only which version of the OS which is baked into the image name as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool?view=azure-pipelines#poolobjectproperties
Reported this in the Github repo where they document the image releases etc, let's see if we get any answers here or there since I couldn't open a support ticket in Azure for some reason on this: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/10506

It seems that the issue is mitigated in this issue.

I believe this is not related to image version but rather due to agent regression that was mitigated earlier today. Is it still happening right now?
If yes, can you enable system diagnostics and share the full Initialize job logs?

Is there a way to specify in the vmImage yml property which version of the VM image one would like to use as a "requirement"?

Unfortunately this is not possible.
